# Left and right inverse

Tags: math-history

Does anybody knows who is the first person to coin the term "left inverse" and "right Inverse" ? And why is it named that way?

Comment: Well it's named that way because that's what it is: for a function $f:X\to Y$, a left inverse is a function $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_X$, and vice versa for a right inverse. I have no idea who coined these terms, and couldn't think of a reason why it would be known, as it is not really a revolutionary concept.

Comment: Good. Very helpful.

Comment: Please do not cross-post questions. This question was already asked [on HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/about-left-right-inverses) a while back.

Comment: Excuse me, but this one is a different question.